80-2000s detective tv show
This is a TV series about pair of detectives (man and woman). I remember most of 2 episode:
1. It starts from showing man, which was hit by a lightning several times(it is very strange in opinion of the main character). They investigate this case and figure out, that people in this town suffer from health problems. Our heroes notice, that they all drink the same milk. They bring it to the lab, which concludes, that this milk contains a high level of quicksilver. They discover a cow farm. There is illegal(don't remember if legal) mine, that will make 1-million profit.
2. One man had a car accident. He was 60-years old but looked like 40-years-old. When autopsy was done, doctors noticed, that he had two hearts. When they investigated it more, they unveiled a plot of people, that stole stem cells from hospitals with purpose to make themselves look younger. I remembered other woman in plot. In the end of this episode detectives talked to some brother and sister and explained them situation with their stem cells.

11th Hour, starring Rufus Sewell
I didn't recognize the description of the lightning episode, but the other one is from 11th Hour, a show I watched a little bit when it first aired. The episode is "Eternal." The first one you mention might be "Electro," but I haven't seen that one, so I can't be sure.

It's possible the OP is confusing 2 episodes. The mercury milk thing is in Minamata.
